# Is any inversion of the usual syntactic word order considered anastrophe/hyperbaton?

Tags: figures-of-speech, hyperbaton

Is any inversion of the usual syntactic word order considered *anastrophe/hyperbaton*?

Sometimes we come across inversions in ordinary writing that need not be necessarily literary in tone— can we apply these labels to writings in such cases too?

Comment: You need to show reasonable research. For a start, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech) has the caveats 'an **intentional** deviation from ordinary language in order to produce a **rhetorical** effect' in its definition of 'figure of speech'. This seems reasonable, and rules out errors and amateurish and spoof candidates.

Comment: Nobody ever uses the words _anastrophe_ or _hyperbaton_ in linguistics; they were terms invented by the Greeks to refer to tricks they could do with ancient Greek, and don't apply to all languages. So use either one, since nobody will be able to correct you if you're wrong.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Nobody? You never know. There might be some ancient Greeks skulking somewhere...